# Не могу понять ошибку в коде. Задание из егэ. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Tags: python

**Задание:**

Исполнитель РазДва преобразует число на экране. У исполнителя есть две команды, которым присвоены номера:

1. Прибавить 1
2. Умножить на 2

Первая команда увеличивает число на экране на 1, вторая умножает его на 2. Программа для исполнителя РазДва — это последовательность команд.
Сколько существует программ, которые преобразуют исходное число 1 в число 20, и при этом траектория вычислений содержит ровно одно из чисел 9 и 10?
Траектория вычислений — это последовательность результатов выполнения всех команд программы. Например, для программы 212 при исходном числе 4 траектория будет состоять из чисел 8, 9, 18.

**Код:**

```
def f(x,y):
    if x > y or x == 10 :
        return 0
    if x == y:
        return 1
    if x < y:
        return f(x+1,y) + f(x*2, y)

def g(a,b):
    if a > b or a == 9 :
        return 0
    if a == b:
        return 1
    if a < b:
        return f(a+1,b) + f(a*2, b)

print((f(1,9)*f(9,20)) + (g(1,10)*g(10,20)))
```

Правильный ответ: 18

У меня ответ: 10

Я не знаю как именно оформить код для этих двух чисел 9 и 10, чтобы было только одно из них в траектории

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно немного упростить:

Есть только один путь из 9 в 20 без десятки 9-18-19-20

Попасть в 10 без девятки можно только из пятёрки.

Остаётся следующее (ответ 18):

```
def f(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return 0
    if x == y:
        return 1
    if x < y:
        return f(x+1,y) + f(x*2, y)

print((f(1,9) + f(1,5)*f(10,20)))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если использовать мой код, то как его видоизменить, чтобы не было ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

```
def g(a,b):
    if a > b or a == 9 :
        return 0
    if a == b:
        return 1
    if a < b:
        return f(a+1,b) + f(a*2, b)
```

в последней строчке опечатка, там должна быть g